# How update entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I insert object to List and save.

> Table Desk(int auto incriment ID,
>   varchar NAME)

```
var desk = new Desk()
           {
           name = "newName"
           };

m_RoomsContext.Desks.Add(desk);
m_RoomsContext.SubmitChanges();
```

//desk.id == 0

I need get id the desk. How to do this?

property id:

```
/// <summary>
    /// No Metadata Documentation available.
    /// </summary>
    [EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty=true, IsNullable=false)]
    [DataMemberAttribute()]
    public global::System.Int32 id
    {
        get
        {
            return _id;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_id != value)
            {
                OnidChanging(value);
                ReportPropertyChanging("id");
                _id = StructuralObject.SetValidValue(value);
                ReportPropertyChanged("id");
                OnidChanged();
            }
        }
    }
    private global::System.Int32 _id;
    partial void OnidChanging(global::System.Int32 value);
    partial void OnidChanged();
```

edmx:

```
 <EntityType Name="Desk">
          <Key>
            <PropertyRef Name="id" />
          </Key>
          <Property Name="id" Type="int" Nullable="false" StoreGeneratedPattern="Identity" />
          <Property Name="width" Type="float" Nullable="false" />
          <Property Name="height" Type="float" Nullable="false" />
          <Property Name="x" Type="int" Nullable="false" />
          <Property Name="y" Type="int" Nullable="false" />
          <Property Name="countMax" Type="int" Nullable="false" />
          <Property Name="countReal" Type="int" />
          <Property Name="date" Type="datetime" />
          <Property Name="id_status" Type="int" Nullable="false" />
        </EntityType>
```

Comment: Is `Id` in your entity model defined with `StoreGeneratedPattern.Identity` (check properties of `Id` property in EDMX file)?

Comment: I update post. no StoreGeneratedPattern.Identity exist.

Answer (score 3):

After you submit look at the `desk.ID` property => it will be assigned the new value from the database.